# Flutter build apk command is throwing errors and is not building apk

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

I am trying to build an apk using flutter, but whenever i run `flutter build apk --release` command, this is the error i am getting.

[image]

The java version i am using is Java 8 but checking the version using cmd shows me this version

`java version "1.8.0_202"                                                                                                Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)                                                                   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)`

Initially i had Java 12 installed but flutter was throwing errors with that.

Contents of MainActivity.kt file

```
package com.example.starter

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unresolved Reference in your MainActivity.kt file, can you also post that?

Comment: posted the contents of MainActivity.kt file.

Comment: hmm, got no clue, if you're targetting android, maybe you can run this inside the android dir ./gradlew assembeleRelease --info if it's failed too. maybe post the log can give us clue

Comment: i couldn't understand, could you please further elaborate if possible? @mangkool

Comment: Try opening android module alone in android studio and  build APK, you will get better error stacktrace which might help you understand what's the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was with kotlin compiler.
I created a new project and Chose `Java` as the language for Android rather than `Kotlin` , copy and replaced my flutter code in this new project, and now Flutter generates the apk just fine.